# Possible to setup Dual Monitor ? I have one VGA port and one DVI Port

Tags: vga, dvi, multiple-monitors

I want to setup dual monitor. I have one VGA Port and one DVI port.

Currently my Dell LCD monitor is connected to VGA Port.

Is there any way to setup dual monitor by plugging other monitor to DVI Port?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On most video cards you can make use of both ports. You should just be able to plug in the monitor and your OS will be able to detect that the port is in use. Assuming you're on Windows, you can then go to the display settings and assign which monitor you want as primary.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have one doubt. Actually i brought a dell LCD which has VGA Port, are there any VGA to DVI converters available ? Thank you.

Comment: @Anil: Yup. They are available: http://www.bing.com/shopping/search?q=dvi%20to%20vga%20adapter&qpvt=dvi+to+vga+adapter

Comment: @Flotsam, Those are DVI to VGA converters. I'm asking about VGA to DVI converter. I already brought a VGA monitor and i only have one DVI port left on my graphics card.

Comment: @Anil Dewani - the adapters in the link are want you are looking for.  They will plug into the DVI port of your video card and provide a VGA connection for your VGA monitor.